# Screenshot de pagina web completa con Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping, screenshot

Tengo un script de web scraping al que debo agregarle una función para tomar una captura de la página completa. Hasta ahora solo he logrado tomar una captura de lo que sería visible al abrir la página, que es menos de 1/4 de lo que ésta contiene...

Me gustaria saber si puedo definir el tamaño que debe abarcar la captura o si puedo seleccinoar el body completo de la pagina web como objetivo de la captura, o tambien si es que puedo seleccionar cada card de producto con algun identificador como id o sku del producto que contiene.

Probé danto tiempo para que cargara o hacer scroll pero no tuve resultados satisfactorios

dejo la url y el código con que tomo la captura. Estoy usando selenium y beautifulSoup

url= https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/category/cat3205/Refrigeradores

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'    )
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
driver.save_screenshot("capturaSelenium1.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de varios intentos logré sacar una screenshot en buena calidad y de la webpage completa con el siguiente codigo. EL nombre del archivo es de acuerdo a la url de origen y la fecha para dejar un registro histórico.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from datetime import date    


url = 'https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/category/cat3205/Refrigeradores'

#obtener dimensiones de webpage. Incluir la ruta de chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\XXX\XXX\chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
#Esperar por 5 segundos para que la página cargue
time.sleep(5)
height = driver.execute_script("return Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight )")
driver.close()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument(f"--window-size=1920,{height}")
options.add_argument("--hide-scrollbars")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\XXX\XXX\chromedriver', options=options)


driver.get(url)
#esperar 5 segundos para cargar todo el contenido y scripts
time.sleep(5)

#manipular url y fecha para dar nombre al screenshot 
url_name_pic = url
x = url_name_pic.split("/")
x1 = x[2].split(".").pop(1)
x2 = x[-1]
today = date.today().isoformat()

print(f'{x1}-{x2}-{today}.png')
driver.save_screenshot(f'{x1}-{x2}-{today}.png')

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Que extraño lo que te esta sucediendo. En java siempre me captura la pantalla completa de la pestaña.

Pruebes probar lo siguiente:

- Maximizar el navegador antes de ingresar la url
- Generar un método que te haga la acción de capturar evidencias.

Si fuese java te comentaria la accion exacta.
Te dejo un link en donde se ve algo parecido: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver

https://www.browserstack.com/guide/take-screenshot-with-selenium-python

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me sirvió de guía para encontrar la solución (la dejo publicada acá mismo)